# Java - determine the position change of array

Tags: java, arrays, count, numbers, position

I have an understanding problem in my code but in a very specific row which is marked in the code below:

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    arrayTest(); 

}

public static void printArray(int [] a) {
    for(int i= 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i] + ""); 
    }
}
public static void arrayTest() {
    int [] numbers = new int [4]; 
    numbers[0] = 1; 
    numbers[1] = 2; 
    numbers[2] = 3; 
    numbers[3] = 4; 
    numbers[numbers[1]] = numbers.length + numbers[0];  // <= what is exactly happening here? 
    printArray(numbers); 
} }
```

the output looks like the following:
1
2
5
4

Why is the number 5 on numbers[2] and not on numbers[1]?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: you are storing the sum in the index 2  numbers[ numbers[1] ] means fetch the values at index 1, which is 2, thus your sum is being stored at the index 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's use other values for simplicity:

```
numbers is [10,20,30,40]
At index -> 0  1  2  3
   values-> 10 20 30 40

number[at index 1] -> 20 (Here 1 is the index, 20 is the value)

number[number[1]] -> number[20] -> OutOfBoundsError as the array size is 4
number[number[0]] -> number[10] -> OutOfBoundsError as the array size is 4
```

In your case:

```
numbers[numbers[1]] = number.length + numbers[0];
numbers[2] = 4 + 1
numbers[2] = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers[numbers[1]] = numbers.length + numbers[0];
```

is equivalent to

```
numbers[2] = numbers.length + numbers[0];
                    4       +      1       == 5
```

since `numbers[1] == 2`.